# SVGjs Image - changing colors with Fill & Stroke not working

Tags: fill, svg.js

I am loading an SVG image with SVG.js, which works as expected.
When I try to change the color using fill or stroke, it does not seem to work.

I have tried `fill()`, `stroke()`, `attr()`, css, etc.

Does fill work on images?

https://jsfiddle.net/9mL8c2q0/

Comment: No full does not work in images. You have to have the svg image as source in your Dom. Then you can change it